# Clear multi dimensional Object in Java

Tags: java, arrays, object

I want to pass 4 arrays from a method which is in A class, to a method in B class. 
I create an instance of class A in the method which is in class B to get the arrays.

The method in A class is defined as Object[] and I use:

```
return new Object[]{Array1,Array2,Array3,Array4};
```

to return the arrays.

In method of B class I get the arrays with an object defined as:

```
private Object outGeoObj[] = new Object[4];
```

I am retrieving successfully the arrays, but I want to clear the object before I use it again. I tried:

```
public void ClearValues(){
    if (outGeoObj != null){
        outGeoObj = null;
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Object is null");
    }  
}
```

but it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

**Minimal Working Example:**

Class B:

```
public class MainFem {

private OutGeoMesh outmesh;
private Object outGeoObj[] = new Object[4]; // [0: Xmpoint, 1: Ympoint, 2: Vec, 3: numpoints]


public MainFem() {
    outmesh = new OutGeoMesh();
}

public void ClearValues(){

    if (outGeoObj != null){
        for(int i = 0; i < outGeoObj.length; i++) {
             outGeoObj[i] = null;
        }
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Object is null");
    }  

} // END Method ClearValues



public void MainStart(int Xpoint[][], int Ypoint[][], int nump[], int c2, int Line[][][], DrawPanel drawPanel){

    outGeoObj = outmesh.createOutGeomesh(Xpoint, Ypoint, nump, c2, Line, drawPanel);

     int temp = (int[][]) outGeoObj[3];
     System.out.println(temp[0][0]);

   }// End Method MainStart
} // END CLASS MainFem
```

Class A:

```
public class OutGeoMesh {

private double Xmpoint[][][] = new double[500][200][20];  
private double Ympoint[][][] = new double[500][200][20];
private double Vec[][][] = new double[500][2][20];  
private int numpoints[][] = new int[500][20];  

public OutGeoMesh() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public Object[] createOutGeomesh(int Xpoint[][], int Ypoint[][], int nump[], int c2, int Line[][][], DrawPanel drawPanel) {

  for (int j = 0; j <= c2; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < nump[j]; i++) {

            Vec[i][0][j] = i;
            Vec[i][1][j] = i+1;

            Xmpoint[i][0][j] = Xpoint[i][j];
            Ympoint[i][1][j] = Ypoint[i][j];

            numpoints[i][j] = numpoints[i][j] + 1;

      } // END FOR i

    } // END FOR j


 return new Object[]{Xmpoint,Ympoint,Vec,numpoints};

} // END METHOD createOutGeomesh
// ---------------------------------

} // END CLASS OutGeoMesh
```

Comment: It's not really clear from the questions _how_ classes `A` and `B` interact and also what is the actual problem? It would help if you posted some more code from the involved classes.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? From what your code shows, you're not clearing the values, you're just simply making `outGeoObj == null`. I think that you're wanting to reset all the values, so you can do `outGeoObj = new Object[outGeoObj.length];`. Or you may want to clear out the arrays in the array, so use a `for loop` for the `outGeoObj` and then a `nested for loop` for each array in your array, and set their values accordingly.

Comment: Loop through the array, assign null to the values?

Comment: @CoderMusgrove  I tried outGeoObj = new Object[outGeoObj.length]; and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do something like this:

```
Arrays.fill(outGeoObj, null);
```

The reason that your code doesn't work is because you are only erasing your reference to the array, but other parts of your code are still using that same array. By using `Arrays.fill` you can erase the contents of the array.